# Sharing database connection witihin Symfony2 functional test between test code and code being tested

Tags: sqlite, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to use SQLite in memory storage to improve speed of my functional tests suite. At the moment it's not possible to take advantage of this feature, as explained here:
https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/2901

So I'm trying to find a workaround. The way I see it, I should get satisfactory results, if I manage to ensure there is single connection used for db set up (loading fixtures), within app being tested (for writing actual data into db) and for asserting db writes. I control connection for setup and for assert-reads manually, but I need a way to ensure my client uses the same connection as well. I'm also using Liip\FunctionalTestBundle. Is there a way to inject a connection into a client created by this line:

```
$this->client = $this->makeClient();
```

Without any hacking

```
Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOSqlite\Driver::connect
```

is being called multiple times, I need it to run just once, without changing any of the production code.